# How can I select rows from database where column Name contains exactly 5 digits

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database with some count of rows. They contains information about books. And I need to select books with Name which contain EXACTLY 5 numbers.
I tried to select by

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE Name LIKE “*#*#*#*#*#*”
```

But result by this query returning books with names which contain more than 5 digits

For example, I have some rows (Names of books):

1. To Kill a Mockingbird **2**
2. **1984 2**
3. The Lord of the Rings (The Lord of the Rings, #**1**-**3**)
4. The Chronicles of Narnia (Chronicles of Narnia, #**1**,**2**,**3**,**4**,**5**,**6**,**7**)

And query, what I need, must return 2 but not 4 item

Comment: You probably mean 5 _digits_, i.e. a 5 digit number.

Comment: which DBMS are you using? add tag to your question

Comment: @jarlh , no, I don’t mean a 5-digit number. I need to get rows where Name count of digits is 5

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: @S.Vladimir the answer I've posted should fix your problem

Comment: @jarlh see the question post

Comment: can you please clarify if you want exactly 5 digits or not? you say exactly 5 but you also want to return item number 4 which has 7 digits

Comment: oh, I`m sorry. Yes, i need exactly 5 digit. I edited the post

Comment: Is this homework or a real world problem? Seems like a very strange requirement. You will need a custom VBA function for that.

Comment: @Andre Yes, this is homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, that was very and very easy.

```
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE Name LIKE "*#*#*#*#*#*" AND Name NOT LIKE "*#*#*#*#*#*#*"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select all books with a certain number of digits you can use a `LIKE` clause checking for multiple digit ranges.

```
SELECT  *
FROM books
WHERE Name LIKE '*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*'
```

Comment: It’s not what I need

Comment: I need get row where string contains exactly 5 digits and no matter they are in sequence or not

Comment: Can you explain this better? I mean your question as stated above is " I need to select books with Name wich contain EXACTLY 5 numbers " which I have solved very nicely

Comment: see the question post

Comment: Still does not make sense @S.Vladimir ... how does it have to return 2 and 4 ( where do you count 5 digits ).. I am quite confused

Comment: If I try to make "SELECT * FROM books WHERE Name LIKE "*#*#*#*#*#*"" query, it will return 2 and 4. But it will return and a row where could 6 digits. And I don`t need this

Comment: @S.Vladimir just to make sure you want to only return books that have 5 numbers in them ?

Comment: exactly 5 digits

Comment: @S.Vladimir this should work.. I have edited my answer

Comment: This will also return values with more than 5 digits. I doubt it can be done without VBA.

Comment: @Andre interesting I am trying to come up with solutions but this is getting out of my skill gap :)

Comment: Yes, this query is the same as I wrote higher. So, maybe it`s really a strange requirement. I will recognise this in the evening

Comment: @Andre Oh, I'm sure that's was very hard, yeah.... Check my answer :) I was goind to the learning and suddenly recognised how to build this query

Answer (score 0):

If name column is numeric than you can use this query.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ISNUMERIC(column1) = 1 and LEN(column1) = 5
```

If name column is alphanumeric then you can create one function which gives you no of numeric in string

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNumbers
(@str VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @str)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @str = STUFF(@str, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @str )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@str,0)
END
GO
```

Once function gets created, you can use this query

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE LEN(dbo.GetNumbers(column1)) = 5
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following statement with your table name and column name:

```
select yt.*, regexp_substr(<book_name>, '[[:digit:]]+',1, 1)
  from <YOUR_TABLE> yt
 where length(regexp_substr(<book_name>, '[[:digit:]]+',1, 1) ) = 5
;
```

Comment: This construction is enough complicated

Comment: This is the exact solution of what you are looking for. Statement written in oracle sql and you can find same function for your language.